# GetAxisLabel always passes -1 for ValueIndex

Tags: teechart

I need to be able to format the X Axis labels on a TeeChart Standard 2012 chart. I’m handling the GetAxisLabel event, but the ValueIndex is always -1.

I found this bit of documentation:

Axis Labels are Values.
In this case, the Series parameter will be nil, and the ValueIndex will be -1.

Axis Labels are Series points.
The Series parameter will be a valid TChartSeries, and the ValueIndex will be the current Series point position.

The problem is that I can find no way to set the Axis Labels to series points.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LabelStyle to be:

```
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.LabelStyle:=talPointValue;
```

or

```
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.LabelStyle:=talText;
```

in your chart. Then you'll be able to do something like this:

```
procedure TForm2.Chart1GetAxisLabel(Sender: TChartAxis; Series: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer; var LabelText: string);
begin
  if ((Series <> nil) and (ValueIndex <> -1)) then
  begin
    LabelText:=FormatFloat('#.00', Series.XValue[ValueIndex]);
  end;
end;
```

However, it's much easier to achieve what the method above does using [AxisValuesFormat](http://www.steema.net/teechartdocs/TChartAxis.AxisValuesFormat.html) property:

```
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.AxisValuesFormat:='#.00';
```

Comment: I can't just set the format string beause the format will change depending upon the X Axis value.

Comment: I'd already tried all of the available LabelStyle values. I just verified that I get -1 for ValueIndex when setting LabelStyle to either taxText or talPointValue.

Comment: @casterle could you please explain what would you like to do with axis labels exactly? A simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here would help. You can post your files at http://www.steema.net/upload/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My application monitors a variable number data series where the data is read from hardware registers on the equipment we are testing.

Comment: Each point on the X Axis represents a variable amount of time, from milliseconds to hours. The width of the chart can be from 5 minutes to days.

Comment: I need to format my labels to reflect the currently displayed time offsets in a format suited to the offset value.

Comment: I hope that's enough detail that you do not need a sample project.

Comment: @casterle, I'm sorry but this: "I need to format my labels to reflect the currently displayed time offsets in a format suited to the offset value." is a little bit too vague of a specification for me so that I can try to arrange an example. Could you please elaborate on that or create a very simple project with random data so that we can try to help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was buiding the demo when I found I could not reproduce the problem. I guess I've got something set in my chart which is causing the ValueIndex to be set to -1. At any rate, I know how to get the event to fire now, so thank you.

Comment: @casterle you're welcome. I'm glad to hear you found a solution.